# I'm making an application using external libraries, and am worried about crediting them properly

Tags: java

I am currently working on a Java application and have found some external libraries I want to use. Since this is my first application, I don't know if I can use them, and if I can, how to credit them. 
I was wondering if someone with some experience could explain how using and crediting external libraries worked.

If it matters, the external libraries are:

JXGrabKey (http://sourceforge.net/projects/jxgrabkey/)

OSSupport (https://bitbucket.org/agynamix/ossupport-connector/overview)

JIntelliType (see comments for link)

Comment: JIntelliType link : https://code.google.com/p/jintellitype/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking a legal question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I will point out this is probably better asked at [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) than at Stack Overflow. It depends on the individual libraries. Libraries are normally provided under one or more licenses, which explain what permissions, restrictions and requirements are conferred to you.

The JXGrabKey page you linked says it's licensed under the GNU Library or Lesser General Public License version 3.0 (LGPLv3), which is good news for you. Check that LGPLv3 link out, **read the license**, and look it up on Wikipedia (or ask about it on Programmers SE) if you need help understanding your rights and requirements under the LGPL.

Agynamix doesn't seem to have a license listed on the page you linked, and in any situation where you aren't told what license the content is available under, I would suggest that you are **not** licensed to use it at all (n.b. I am not a lawyer). You may want to look through the sources, as distribution-quality source code generally have a license boilerplate in a comment at the start of each file.

JIntellitype's page shows that it is provided under the Apache License 2.0. Again, read the license and make sure you understand it before you distribute any software that includes this library.